# Segner's Recurrence Relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recurrence-relations

Why is Segner's Recurrence Relation formula valid. Does anyone know how to prove it?

I can't seem to understand why this formula works/is true.

$$C_0 = 1,\quad C_{n+1} = C_0C_n + C_1C_{n−1}+ \cdots + C_kC_{n−k} + \cdots + C_nC_0\text{ ?}$$

Where Cn denotes the valid list of open and closed parentheses of length 2n

*valid meaning the number of open parentheses is greater than or equal to closed parentheses

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the formula is in the post

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen oh sorry, i edited it!

Answer (score 1):

I looked it up.
The formula,
according to mathworld,
is
$ E_n=E_2E_{n-1}+E_3E_{n-2}+...+E_{n-1}E_2 $,
where
$E_n$ is the number of ways
of dividing a polygon by diagonals.

The way I look at this,
is that each of the terms
($E_k E_{n-k+1}$)
represents a division of
the polygon into two subpolygons
by a single diagonal.

The two terms in the product
represent the 
number of ways
each subpolygon
can,
in turn,
be divided by diagonals.

I know this is moderately
hand-wavey,
but it's my way 
of understanding
the formula.

Comment: How would you interpret this recurrence relation in the context of counting the number of full binary trees with $n + 1$ leaves (= $C_n$)?